# With PHRETS v2, Can I Sort the Data Fields Alphabetically? (Had this when using V1)

Tags: phrets

This code works in terms of retrieving data:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');

require_once("composer/vendor/autoload.php");

$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('my_url')
        ->setUsername('my_user')
        ->setPassword('my_pass')
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');

$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
$connect = $rets->Login();
$system = $rets->GetSystemMetadata();
echo "Server Name: " . $system->getSystemDescription();

$property_classes = ['Property'];

foreach ($property_classes as $pc) {
    // generate the DMQL query
    
$query = "(BedroomsTotal=1+),(MlsStatus=ACT,PND)";

$results = $rets->Search('Property', $pc, $query);
 
file_put_contents('MyFolder/Property_' . $pc . '.csv', $results->toCSV());
   
} //end for each property class

php?>
```

I would like to know how to sort the fields alphabetically, in order to keep fields in a predicable order, which could also be used in an SQL CREATE TABLE statement. I had this ability with v1.

I would also like to be able to loop through the data fields with a FOR EACH kind of statement, in order to create a customized field delimiter; a custom delimiter helps with avoiding import errors in cases where the delimiter also appears within the metadata, such as quotes and commas within remarks section.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you tried selecting the fields you aren't able to pull back in the full query?

Comment: Are you using the COMPACT format?

Comment: I shortened the question, and I believe above comments are no longer applicable.